# shell script executed in HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html, shell, arguments

I have some basic knowledge of HTML/PHP. The situation I am facing is frustrating. What I want to accomplish is to create a simple search box on a web page, when the user puts in input and clicks submit then my shell script is executed and then presented on a php page. I have been successful in getting other commands to run when I click submit to make sure the PHP exec shell command is working. 
I will see the output on the web page. Just not my script. My script uses an argument to pass and works thru command line. Below is the details of my script, HTML, and PHP page. Also, I'm using a FreeBSD 10 box.

**My Script**

Command Line - 
$ csearch "argument"

```
#!/bin/sh
grep -ir -B 1 -A 4 "$*" /usr/local/var/rancid/CiscoDevices/configs
```

**My HTML page**

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="csearch.php">
    <input type="text" name="searchText">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**My PHP page**

```
<?php
$searchText=$_POST['$searchText'];
?>

<html>
<?php

$output = shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/csearch $searchText');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";

?>
</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you basically say "it is not working". this is never a good enough error explanation. be much more specific! give error messages, say what happens, what is supposed to happen, give some intermediate debug info, where does it get to, where not, is the script executed at all but with the wrong parameters, ...

Comment: Thats the thing, there is no error message.  Just a blank page.  I can run the csearch.php page from command line just fine and it outputs, just not thru html, just gives a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/csearch $searchText');` This isn't what you expect it to be:

```
<?php

$searchText = 'foobar';
$cmd = '/usr/local/bin/csearch $searchText';
echo $cmd;

?>
```

outputs:

> /usr/local/bin/csearch $searchText

Change the string to use double quotes and $searchText will actually be what you want to it be:

```
$output = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/csearch $searchText");
```

[More info on the use of quotes in PHP.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

As @uri2x hints in a comment:

`$searchText=$_POST['$searchText'];` should be changed to `$searchText=$_POST['searchText'];` for a similar reason.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the resource page but this did not help.  I tried the double quotes and fixed the variable setup.  Still nothing.   I took your exampe "foobar" above and tried it...it works below is the test I used.  Now if I substitute my script (csearch) for "ls -l" command, I get nothing again, just a blank page.

    `<?php
    
    $searchText = '/usr/local/bin';
    $cmd = shell_exec("ls -l $searchText");
    echo "<pre>$cmd</pre>";
    
    ?>`

Comment: @GentooBob In that last example when you `echo "<pre>$cmd</pre>";`, can you confirm that the `<pre>` tags are being sent to the browser (you'll have to view the source)?

Comment: thanks for your help.  With your corrections and me finding it was permission issues on the directory that contained the config files it has been fixed.  Thanks for your help!